# Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region about the y-axis

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, rotations, volume

Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by

$y=5\sin(5x^2)$, $0 \le x \le \sqrt{(\frac\pi5)}$

about the $y$-axis.

I get the wrong answer using the cylindrical shell formula, so I assume I am plugging the values into the wrong place. I ended up with "$-\pi$" and that is the wrong answer.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this please

Comment: Use integration. @Cluckles

Comment: Find $\int_{a}^{b}2\pi xy(x)dx$

Comment: I did, and then I use u substitution for 5x^2. After integrating I  still end up with the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
V = 2\pi\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi/5}}5x\sin(5x^2)dx \to \pi\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(u)du = 2\pi.
$$